# python unrecognized URL

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am creating a small project as Twitch views bots in python for live streams views boosting and its consist of URL, Bot count , proxies list and VLC.
the code has ran with no errors just every time I run it , it says cant access URL..

```
import concurrent.futures, time, random, os

# desired channel url
channel_url = 'https://www.twitch.tv/username'
# number of viewer bots
botcount = 20
# path to proxies.txt file
proxypath = "C:/Users/user/Desktop/proxies.txt"
# path to vlc
playerpath = r'"C:/Program Files(x86)/VideoLAN/VLC"'


# takes proxies from proxies.txt and returns to list
def create_proxy_list(proxyfile, shared_list):
    with open(proxyfile, 'r') as file:
        proxies = [line.strip() for line in file]
    for i in proxies:
        shared_list.append((i))


    return shared_list


# takes random proxies from the proxies list and adds them to another list
def randproxy(proxylist, botcount):
    randomproxylist = list()
    for _ in range(botcount):
        proxy = random.choice(proxylist)
        randomproxylist.append(proxy)
        proxylist.remove(proxy)
    return (randomproxylist)


# launches a viewer bot after a short delay
def launchbots(proxy):
    time.sleep(random.randint(5, 20))
    os.system(
        f'streamlink --player={playerpath} --player-no-close --player-http  --hls-segment-timeout 30 --hls-segment-attempts 3 --retry-open 1 --retry-streams 1 --retry-max 1 --http-stream-timeout 3600 --http-proxy {proxy} {channel_url} worst')


# calls the launchbots function asynchronously
def main(randomproxylist):
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executer:
        executer.map(launchbots, randomproxylist)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(randproxy(create_proxy_list(proxypath, shared_list=list()), botcount))
```

[Console error shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qH7YD.png)
[running streamlink on CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37jNW.jpg)

Comment: The error seems to suggest you either haven't installed streamlink or it is not in path. Try opening a command prompt and running the `streamlink`.

Comment: Which Python version are you actually using? Why tag this with two different major versions? Also, include the output as text, not as picture, along with the [mcve] that produces it.

Comment: i have streamlink and its running on CMD well

Comment: i tagged two versions as i have tried it on both versions same error